# Trying to insert rows but SQL only inserts 1

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert different numbers of rows into my table by adjusting @s:=1 and @s<1000 but it only inserts one at a time. What am I doing wrong?

```
INSERT INTO
    rent
    (
    id
    )
select @s:=@s+1 as seq
FROM (SELECT @s:=1) AS baseview, rent
WHERE @s<1000
ORDER by @s ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?:

```
INSERT INTO
    rent
    (
    id
    )
SELECT seq FROM (
    select @s:=@s+1 as seq
    FROM (SELECT @s:=1) AS baseview, rent
    WHERE @s<1000
    ORDER by @s ASC
) seqSource;
```